# C++ Iterators for multi-dimensional C arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, iterator, boost-iterators

I have a large number of 3 to 6-dimensional C arrays I need to iterate through. More C++'y representation like boost::multi_array isn't an option as these arrays come via the C framework PETSc (using fortran ordering, hence the backward indexing). Straightforward loops end up looking something like this:

```
  for (int i=range.ibeg; i<=range.iend; ++i){
   for (int j=range.jbeg; j<=range.jend; ++j){
     for (int k=range.kbeg; k<=range.kend; ++k){
       (...)
```

or even worse:

```
  for (int i=range.ibeg-1; i<=range.iend+1; ++i){
    for (int j=range.jbeg-1; j<=range.jend+1; ++j){
      for (int k=range.kbeg-1; k<=range.kend+1; ++k){
       for (int ii=0; ii<Np1d; ++ii){
        for (int jj=0; jj<Np1d; ++jj){
         for (int kk=0; kk<Np1d; ++kk){
           data[k][j][i].member[kk][jj][ii] = 
            func(otherdata[k][j][i].member[kk][jj][ii],
                 otherdata[k][j][i].member[kk][jj][ii+1]);
```

There are many instances like this, with varying ranges on the loop indexes, and it all gets very ugly and potentially error prone. How should one construct iterators for multi-dimensional arrays like this?

Comment: just looking at that makes me shiver...

Comment: You and me both, but this is the world I live in.

Comment: recursion? There ARE cases where recursion is superior. If you couple it with templates you could even get everything inlined.

Comment: Can you give a code example?

Comment: Can you treat a Foo[X][Y][Z] as a Foo[X*Y*Z]? Then foo[i][j][k] becomes [i+j*X+k*X*Y]. Or is this just something that happens to work and isn't guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: The data is guaranteed to be contiguous so yes that mapping does nominally work (I've done it with #define IDX(i,j,k) functions in the past) but I need to avoid it. PETSc does a lot of pointer arithmetic in the background allowing for things like negative indices that could be problematic.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Well if you don't need the individual coordinates during computation, it's trivial to reduce to a single `for` loop that counts until the size of the entire n-dimensional array. This is also much more efficient because you don't need to compute `i+j*X+k*X*Y`. But you usually do need individual coordinates, e.g. `ii` vs `ii+1` in the example given. That's why I suggested an n-dimensional counter in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fully templated version was not so hard after all, so here it is in a separate answer, again with [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d1a469b27b23877). If I'm not mistaken, this should have zero overhead on top of custom nested loops. You could measure and let me know. I intend to implement this for my own purposes anyway, that's why I put this effort here.

```
template<size_t N>
using size = std::integral_constant<size_t, N>;

template<typename T, size_t N>
class counter : std::array<T, N>
{
    using A = std::array<T, N>;
    A b, e;

    template<size_t I = 0>
    void inc(size<I> = size<I>())
    {
        if (++_<I>() != std::get<I>(e))
            return;

        _<I>() = std::get<I>(b);
        inc(size<I+1>());
    }

    void inc(size<N-1>) { ++_<N-1>(); }

public:
    counter(const A& b, const A& e) : A(b), b(b), e(e) { }

    counter& operator++() { return inc(), *this; }

    operator bool() const { return _<N-1>() != std::get<N-1>(e); }

    template<size_t I>
    T& _() { return std::get <I>(*this); }

    template<size_t I>
    constexpr const T& _() const { return std::get <I>(*this); }
};
```

Instead of `operator[]` I now have method `_` (feel free to rename), which is just a shortcut for `std::get`, so usage is not so much more verbose than with `operator[]`:

```
    for (counter<int, N> c(begin, end); c; ++c)
        cout << c._<0>() << " " << c._<1>() << " " << c._<2>() << endl;
```

In fact, you may try the previous version

```
    for (counter<int, N> c(begin, end); c; ++c)
        cout << c[0] << " " << c[1] << " " << c[2] << endl;
```

and measure, because it may be equivalent. For this to work, switch `std::array` inheritance to `public` or declare `using A::operator[];` in `counter`'s `public` section.

What is definitely different is `operator++`, which is now based on recursive template function `inc()` and the problematic condition `if (n < N - 1)` is replaced by a specialization (actually, overload) that has no overhead.

If it turns out that there is overhead eventually, an ultimate attempt would be to replace `std::array` by `std::tuple`. In this case, `std::get` is the only way; there is no `operator[]` alternative. It will also be weird that type `T` is repeated `N` times. But I hope this won't be needed.

Further generalizations are possible, e.g. specifying a (compile-time) increment step per dimension or even specifying arbitrary indirect arrays per dimension, e.g. to simulate

```
a([3 5 0 -2 7], -4:2:20)
```

in Matlab-like syntax.

But this needs even more work, and I think you can take it on from here if you like the approach.

Comment: Awesome, will try this and get back. This will work for arbitrary n-dimensional vectors yes?

Comment: It will work for any combination of 1-dimensional arrays, n-dimensional arrays, custom classes, functions, expressions, or pretty much anything you put inside the block of the single `for` loop. It doesn't hold any data, it just counts and gives you coordinates `c[0], c[1], ...` that you can use as you like.

Comment: @Aurelius Of course, one requirement is random access to the underlying array(s). Otherwise, you would need the counter/iterator to hold a reference to the data and increment an underlying iterator instead of an integer coordinate. This is yet another generalization.

Comment: Outstanding answer. With a debug compile this solution is about 10% slower than the C loops, and identical with -O3 compile. This dramatically cleans up my code. If you accept beer as payment send me an address ;)

Answer (score 3):

A full-blown n-dimensional iterator is not necessary in your simple case of nested `for` loops. Since a single traversal is only needed, a simple counter is enough, which is easily custom-made like this:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class counter
{
    using A = std::array<T, N>;
    A b, i, e;

public:
    counter(const A& b, const A& e) : b(b), i(b), e(e) { }

    counter& operator++()
    {
        for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        {
            if (++i[n] == e[n])
            {
                if (n < N - 1)
                    i[n] = b[n];
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    operator bool() { return i[N - 1] != e[N - 1]; }

    T&       operator[](size_t n)       { return i[n]; }
    const T& operator[](size_t n) const { return i[n]; }
};
```

It is then very easy to use this counter like this:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr size_t N = 3;
    using A = std::array<int, N>;

    A begin = {{0, -1,  0}};
    A end   = {{3,  1,  4}};

    for (counter<int, N> c(begin, end); c; ++c)
        cout << c << endl;
        // or, cout << c[0] << " " << c[1] << " " << c[3] << endl;
}
```

assuming there's an operator `<<` for `counter`. See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98a2a1f63c980ea6) for full code.

The innermost condition `if (n < N - 1)` accounts for being able to check for termination and is not so efficient to always check. It was not so apparent to me how to factor it out, but anyhow it only takes place when we advance to the next "digit" of the counter, not at every increment operation.

Instead of using `c[0], c[1], c[2]` etc., it is more efficient to use `std::get` if `counter` derives `std::array` instead of having member `i` (while `b,e` remain members). This idea can be extended towards a compile-time recursive implementation of `operator++` (`operator bool` as well) that would eliminate the `for` loop inside it, along with the problematic check discussed above. `operator[]` would be discarded in this case. But all this would make `counter` code more obscure and I just wanted to highlight the idea. It would also make usage of `counter` a bit more verbose, but that's a price you'd need to pay for efficiency.

Of course, a full-blown n-dimensional iterator can be built by extending `counter` with more methods and traits. But to make it generic enough may be a huge undertaking.

Comment: Very neat solution, I'll work this out Monday and get back. Can you edit the example for std::get? This is performance critical code; multi-day runtimes on 100+ cores for even the best implementation, so anything significantly slower than the C-style loops is a non-starter.

Comment: I misunderstood initially... it absolutely needs to be a "full-blown n-dimensional" (or 3,5, and 6-D) iterator as we're not looping through all of the array data, but only limited sections of it. e.g., data may be in an array a[nk][nj][ni], and some functions will need to iterate through all of it, but most will operate on some subset like a[1:nk-1][0:nj][0]

Comment: Well, ok I understand. And yes, the fully templated code can indeed take zero overhead as required, but needs some more work to make :-) I'll try. In the meantime, you can try this one and measure.

Comment: Thanks, it's already given me a good idea on how to move forward. Ironically this type of thing is fantastically easy in Fortran, where one can just write a(ibeg:iend,jbeg:jend,kbeg:kend) = ...

Comment: @Aurelius This is not a problem. By "full-blown" *iterator* I meant birectional or random access, type traits, etc. What you say here can be customized by appropriate initialization of `begin`, `end` arrays.

Comment: @Aurelius It's also fantastically easy in Matlab and many languages as well. That's one of my motivations begind [ivl](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2), but that is being developed for years, that's why I said "huge undertaking".

Comment: Agreed; working in HPC and numerical methods, the lack of any adequate way to handle multidimensional arrays is the one major detractor to using C++, and it's a major problem. boost::multiarray, boost::ublas, eigen, blitz++, TNT, armadillo, etc., all have severe problems with them.